# Angular 2 boostrap datepicker disable other dates not working

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I'm currently using the angular bootstrap datepicker(Basic Datepicker) from the examples https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

My issue is that how do I disable the other dates aside from the selected date I set? 
Example: July 13 is selected, the other dates are all disabled.

Thanks and Looking Forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need but it may put you on the right track:
You can restrict dates to a specific day by modifying the global configuration example at the bottom of the page you referenced

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDatepickerConfig, NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-config',
  templateUrl: 'src/datepicker-config.html',
  providers: [NgbDatepickerConfig] // add NgbDatepickerConfig to the component 
providers
})
export class NgbdDatepickerConfig {

  model;

  constructor(config: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
    // customize default values of datepickers used by this component tree
    config.minDate = {year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1};
    config.maxDate = {year: 2099, month: 12, day: 31};

    // days that don't belong to current month are not visible
    config.outsideDays = 'hidden';

    // everyday but today is disabled
    config.markDisabled = (date: NgbDateStruct) => {
      const today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      const d = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
      return d.getTime() !== today.getTime();
    };
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply I appreciate it. But this will only work on the current date. What if for a predefined date  or like multiple dates like only [14, 15, 16] and the rest are disabled.   Hoping for your feedback. Thanks

Comment: I'd just put different logic in the config.markdisabled function so instead of checking today's date (`return d.getTime() !== today.getTime();`) it would instead check the date/dates that I'm interested in  e.g. `return d.getTime() !== myDateVariable.getTime();`

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't work, I tried something like `if (d.getDate() != 4 || d.getDate() != 5 || d.getDate() != 6) {   return true;   }` but it disabled all dates. Can you please give an actual example? Thanks

Comment: You can't compare a date with a number like `4`, `5` or `6` - You need to compare dates. One way(and I think the simplest way) to compare dates is to use the getTime() function, which returns the date in milliseconds(read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)) --
So an example of how you might compare the 5th of July could be:
`var myDate = new Date(2018, 07, 05);`
`return d.getTime() !== myDate.getTime();`